# How do I invoke a recursive construtor in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, recursion, constructor, overloading, constructor-overloading

I have a class constructor overload, and I want to invoke the constructor recursively depending on the arguments provided.

```
class Matrix {
    /**
     * Construct a new Matrix given the entries.
     * @param   arr the entries of the matrix
     */
    constructor(arr?: number[][]);

    /**
     * Construct a new Matrix given the size.
     * @param   rows the number of rows (matrix height)
     * @param   cols the number of columns (matrix width)
     */
    constructor(rows?: number, cols?: number);

    constructor(rows: number[][]|number = 0, cols: number = 0) {
        function isMatrixRaw(m: any): m is number[][] {
            // return `true` if m is of type number[][]
        }
        if (isMatrixRaw(rows)) {
            // ...
            // do all the main work here
            // ...
        } else { // typeof rows === 'number' && typeof cols === 'number'
            let m: number[][];
            // ...
            // create a 2D array of numbers, given rows and cols
            // recursively call the constructor with the new 2D array
            // ...
            new Matrix(m) // <-- is this right?
        }
    }
}
```

The main constructor work is done if the argument is a 2-dimensional array of entries, but I also want an overload: to provide a row size and column size (for example, `new Matrix(2,3)`). If `rows` and `cols` are numbers, I want to create a 2-dimensional array and then pass that new array back into the constructor.

How do recursive constructor calls work in TypeScript? Do I call `new Matrix()`, `return new Matrix()`, `this.constructor()`, `Matrix.constructor()`, or something else?

Comment: Why not just put the initialization of the 2D array before and procede with the main part of the init after `rows` is `number[][]`. `if (!isMatrixRaw(rows)) { rows = [[0]] } // do all the work after`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm not sure what you mean. I want the overload to allow something like `new Matrix(2,3)` which would then create an array like `[ [0,0,0], [0,0,0] ]` and pass that back into the constructor.

Comment: I mean something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dkhurp

Comment: you can call another recursive function within the constructor and pass these parameters to it and then it returns the result to the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a value from the constructor. The returned value will be the result of the `new` operation:

```
class Matrix {
    public rows: number[][];
    constructor(arr: number[][]);
    constructor(rows: number, cols: number);
    constructor(rows: number[][]|number = 0, cols: number = 0) {
        function isMatrixRaw(m: any): m is number[][] { return m instanceof Array; }
        if (!isMatrixRaw(rows)) {
            // init rows with an array
            rows = new Array(rows).fill(0).map(_ => new Array(cols).fill(0));
            return new Matrix(rows);
        } else {
            this.rows = rows; // it's a number[][] now for sure
        }
    }
}
```

You might consider reorganizing  your code so this extra call is not necessary. Just do the check first and then do the bulk of your constructor work as if the invocation was done with `number[][]`

```
class Matrix {
    public rows: number[][];
    constructor(arr: number[][]);
    constructor(rows: number, cols: number);
    constructor(rows: number[][]|number = 0, cols: number = 0) {
        function isMatrixRaw(m: any): m is number[][] { return m instanceof Array; }
        if (!isMatrixRaw(rows)) {
            // init rows with an array
            rows = new Array(rows).fill(0).map(_ => new Array(cols).fill(0));
        }
        this.rows = rows; // it's a number[][] now for sure
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your first code block will fail with both `--strictNullChecks` and `--strictPropertyInitialization` on, because TS does not detect `this.rows` being set inside the `if` clause (even though we know it will by recursion).